# See Which User Created/Edited Block?

Tags: 7, users, blocks

Is there any way in Drupal 7 to view which user last made edits to a particular block, or who created the block?

Answer (score 1):

STEPS:
1. Start creating a new view by clicking "Add new view" link under Admin > Structure > Views.

2.
a) Type "Other Contents by Author" in "View name" text box.
b) [Optional step.] You can check "Description" checkbox and write a description for view. If you wish, check and write "A list which contains other content by author."

3. Select "Content" from the "Show" select list.
4. Uncheck "Create a page".
5. Check "Create a block". You can enter any block title you wish. To limit the items shown in block, type a number in the "Items per page" text box. (You can change it later.)
6. Click "Continue & edit". At this stage, it is a good idea to click the "Save" button after each alteration/change to save the View.

7.
a) Click the "Advanced" link in right side of the page (if the pane is not open).
b) Click the "add" link in CONTEXTUAL FILTERS row.
c) Check the "Content: Author uid" checkbox from the "Add contextual filters" popup.
d) Click "Apply..." button.
e) Check "Provide default value" option in the WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE section.
f) Select "User ID from URL" from the "Type" select list.
g) Check "Also look for a node and use the node author" checkbox.
h) Click "Apply..." button.

8.
a) Click "add" link again in the CONTEXTUAL FILTERS row.
b) Check "Content: Nid" checkbox from the "Add contextual filters" popup.
c) Click the "Apply..." button.
d) Check "Provide default value" option in the WHEN THE FILTER VALUE IS NOT AVAILABLE section.
e) Select "Content ID from URL" from the "Type" select list.
f) Scroll down to the MORE section and check the "Exclude" checkbox.
g) Click the "Apply..." button.

9. Click the "Save" button and save the view.

You can add different fields and filters and make changes to create solutions for different needs.

Comment: thanks for these detailed instructions! i've followed them and now have a new view/block available ... but i'm still not sure how to use this to investigate **which user created** or **which user last modified** a specific block, for example in here:
mydomain.com/admin/structure/block/manage/block **/1/configure**